# Is it safe to scan nvidia i2c with sensors-detect (lm-sensors)

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, temperature, lm-sensors

I have an RTX 3090, and nvidia-smi is able to provide one temperature, however the video memory tends to run hot in this card and this is not reflected by this number. When I run sensors-detect (from the lm-sensors package) I see several I2C adapters for the card, specifically.

```
Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at a:00.0 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 2 at a:00.0 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 5 at a:00.0 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 6 at a:00.0 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 7 at a:00.0 (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 8 at a:00.0 (i2c-8)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively):
```

Since the default is NO, and I've yet to find someone else who's tried, I'm erring on the side of caution and not probing the ports. However I've read some other stuff which indicates at least one of these might be the temperature probe for the memory I am interested in.

Does anyone know if it is safe to scan all of these? Safe to scan some in particular? Please do let me know if you've tested this, I'd rather not brick this 3090 the same day I got it! I am on ubuntu

OS Info in case it comes up

```
Linux james-desktop 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```